# How to use the follow-chain subcommand in try-runtime?

Tags: testing, try-runtime, test-network

In the try-runtime [documentation](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html), there is note of a [follow-chain](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/enum.Command.html#variant.FollowChain) subcommand which follows the given chain’s finalized blocks and apply all of its extrinsics.

There are also some examples [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/index.html#examples).

I would like a step-by-step instruction of how to use try-runtime's follow-chain subcommand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/substrate
cd substrate
```

Run a dev chain locally. This is the chain that I want to "follow":

```
cargo b -r
cp target/release/node-template .
./node-template --dev
```

Compile with try-runtime:

```
cargo b -r --features=try-runtime
cp target/release/node-template node-template-try-runtime
cp target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/node_template_runtime.wasm runtime-try-runtime.wasm
```

Run the `follow-chain` subcommand:

```
./node-template-try-runtime \
    try-runtime \
    --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm \ 
    -lruntime=debug \
    follow-chain \
    --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

You will get beautiful output like the following:

```
./node-template-try-runtime try-runtime --runtime runtime-try-runtime.wasm -lruntime=debug follow-chain --uri ws://localhost:9944
2023-04-07 10:15:39.620  INFO main try-runtime::cli: subscribing to "chain_subscribeFinalizedHeads" / "chain_unsubscribeFinalizedHeads"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.633  INFO main remote-ext: since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.635  INFO main remote-ext: scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0xb651c240a9b85a0ba7fb7fa297f55c954606264cc4733ebd34249aa3c2a2b95c    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.636  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: 3a6368696c645f73746f726167653a64656661756c743a, took 0s    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.636  INFO main remote-ext: Querying a total of 42 keys from prefix , splitting among 10 threads, 5 keys per thread    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.642  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: , took 0s    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.642  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.645  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7f9cce9c888469bb1a0dceaa129672ef8    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.645  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.645  INFO main remote-ext: initialized state externalities with storage root 0x7687476066905904caba95c9cfb119793ef4d9d36f36bd7d317ee603b3e76186 and state_version V1    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.659  INFO main try-runtime::cli: original spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template")-100, code hash: 9fd0a02fb6e725221ae379fc4d13929c26b90efb4d817d46d7fd64274dd7bb7d    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.666  INFO main try-runtime::cli: new spec: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template")-100, code hash: 4516ccbbd02187bd17a18098c644e3723741d7f30cb75faef2974f389356f6dc    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.782  INFO main runtime::executive: try-runtime: executing block #11 / state root check: false / signature check: true / try-state-select: All    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "System"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Timestamp"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Aura"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Grandpa"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Balances"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "TransactionPayment"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Sudo"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "TemplateModule"    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.783 DEBUG main runtime::system: [11] 0 extrinsics, length: 11 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 839311000, proof_size: 2986) (0%)    
2023-04-07 10:15:39.785  INFO main try-runtime::cli: executed block 11, consumed weight Weight(ref_time: 839311000, proof_size: 2986), new storage root 0x0dc5e9cebb0cc37a19c9a9285e3102a2977509566c5d96dddbf4dee0e48fef23    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.019  INFO main runtime::executive: try-runtime: executing block #12 / state root check: false / signature check: true / try-state-select: All    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "System"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Timestamp"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Aura"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Grandpa"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Balances"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "TransactionPayment"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "Sudo"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support:  try-state pallet "TemplateModule"    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.020 DEBUG main runtime::system: [12] 0 extrinsics, length: 11 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight:Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) op weight Weight(ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0) (0%) / mandatory weight Weight(ref_time: 839311000, proof_size: 2986) (0%)    
2023-04-07 10:15:44.021  INFO main try-runtime::cli: executed block 12, consumed weight Weight(ref_time: 839311000, proof_size: 2986), new storage root 0x7f335319d53bae574dbebff262b28c02825b9c945f2e40eac472e9980758c656
```

And you can see that this will continuously follow the chain!